# Crunchbase Data API v3.1 to Google Sheets

Tags: api, google-sheets

I'm trying to pull data from the Crunchbase Open Data Map to a Google Spreadsheet.  I'm following [Ben Collins's script](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/crunchbase/) but it no longer works since the upgrade from v3 to v3.1.  Anyone had any luck modifying the script for success?

```
var USER_KEY = 'insert your API key in here';

// function to retrive organizations data
function getCrunchbaseOrgs() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Organizations');
  var query = sheet.getRange(3,2).getValue();

  // URL and params for the Crunchbase API
  var url = 'https://api.crunchbase.com/v/3/odm-organizations?query=' + encodeURI(query) + '&user_key=' + USER_KEY;

  var json = getCrunchbaseData(url,query);

  if (json[0] === "Error:") {
    // deal with error with fetch operation
    sheet.getRange(5,1,sheet.getLastRow(),2).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(6,1,1,2).setValues([json]);
  }
  else {
    if (json[0] !== 200) {
      // deal with error from api
      sheet.getRange(5,1,sheet.getLastRow(),2).clearContent();
      sheet.getRange(6,1,1,2).setValues([["Error, server returned code:",json[0]]]);
    }
    else {
      // correct data comes back, filter down to match the name of the entity
      var data = json[1].data.items.filter(function(item) {
        return item.properties.name == query;
      })[0].properties;

      // parse into array for Google Sheet
      var outputData = [
        ["Name",data.name],
        ["Homepage",data.homepage_url],
        ["Type",data.primary_role],
        ["Short description",data.short_description],
        ["Country",data.country_code],
        ["Region",data.region_name],
        ["City name",data.city_name],
        ["Blog url",data.blog_url],
        ["Facebook",data.facebook_url],
        ["Linkedin",data.linkedin_url],
        ["Twitter",data.twitter_url],
        ["Crunchbase URL","https://www.crunchbase.com/" + data.web_path]
      ];

      // clear any old data
      sheet.getRange(5,1,sheet.getLastRow(),2).clearContent();

      // insert new data
      sheet.getRange(6,1,12,2).setValues(outputData);

      // add image with formula and format that row
      sheet.getRange(5,2).setFormula('=image("' + data.profile_image_url + '",4,50,50)').setHorizontalAlignment("center");
      sheet.setRowHeight(5,60);
    }
  }
}
```

This code no longer pulls data as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't confirm about the error messages when you ran the script. So I would like to show about the clear difference point. It seems that the endpoint was changed from `https://api.crunchbase.com/v/3/` to `https://api.crunchbase.com/v3.1/`. So how about this modification?

#### From :

```
 var url = 'https://api.crunchbase.com/v/3/odm-organizations?query=' + encodeURI(query) + '&user_key=' + USER_KEY;
```

#### To :

```
 var url = 'https://api.crunchbase.com/v3.1/odm-organizations?query=' + encodeURI(query) + '&user_key=' + USER_KEY;
```

#### Note :

- From your script, I couldn't also find `query`. So if the script doesn't work even when you modified the endpoint, please confirm about it. You can see the detail of API v3 Compared to API v3.1 is [here](https://data.crunchbase.com/docs/api-v3-compared-to-api-v31).

#### References :

- [API v3 Compared to API v3.1](https://data.crunchbase.com/docs/api-v3-compared-to-api-v31)
- [Using the API](https://data.crunchbase.com/v3/docs/using-the-api)

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: @meow-meow-meow Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved.